# Sorting a QString list by numbers C++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt and I created a ranking scene which contains all the players list with their score, so I have a `QList<QString> list`, every QString contains a name and a score, separated by a space like this  `Mario 50`.
Now the problem is: how can I sort the list by the lowest score?

Comment: It would be solved if you changed the `QList<QString>` into `QMap<int,QString>` where the int is the value and the QString is the name only.

Comment: I was looking for that solution but unfortunately I can't change the format now cause I have too many other functions that use my list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::sort()` with a lambda like this

```
std::sort(str_list.begin(), str_list.end(), [](const QString &lhs, const QString &rhs)
{
    int num_lhs = lhs.split(' ').last().toInt();
    int num_rhs = rhs.split(' ').last().toInt();
    return num_lhs < num_rhs;
});
```